# Solving a first order ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

we have : $x'(t) = (x'_1(t), x'_2(t), x'_3(t))$ and $x(t)=(x_1(t), x_2(t), x_3(t))$
Then the system $x'(t)=Ax(t)+bu$ where A=
\begin{matrix}
        -1 & 1 & 0 \\
         1 & -3 & 1 \\
         0 & 1 & -1 \\
        \end{matrix}
and b= \begin{matrix}
        0 \\
        1  \\
        0  \\
        \end{matrix}
How can I solve the first order ODE :

$x'_1 = x_1 -3x_2 + x_3 $ ?

Comment: what are $x_2$ and $x_3$?

Comment: I have edited the question @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: You can solve for $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$ given $x'(t) = Ax(t)+bu$, which is an inhomogeneous DE. Your question is to solve a homogeneous DE where it is not clear what $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$ represent. Are they $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$ from solving $x'(t) = Ax(t)+bu$? Is that really $x'_1$ on the left hand side?